# NDC+ protocol (NCR Direct Connection) documentation?

Tags: financial, cen-xfs

NDC is an ATM software application protocol from NCR corporation.
Anyone can tell me how to get documentation for NDC / NDC+ / Advanced NDC?
Cause i want to develop simulators and application (both ATM and the Host) based on it.
Thanks.

Comment: NDC Protocols are not open. If your company has got a NCR ATM, you can find the documentation on ATM CDs.